# My SQL requires a user has logged in successfully once before, how can I modify to remove that requirement?

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is my SQL

```
'SELECT u.`id`, 
               u.`email`, 
               u.`password`, 
               u.`first_name`, 
               u.`last_name`,
               u.`role_id`,
               MAX( ul.`datetime` ) as `last_login`,
               SUM( ul.`failed` ) as `failed_logins`
        FROM `users` `u`
        JOIN ( SELECT `user_id`, `datetime`, `failed`
               FROM `user_logins`
               ORDER BY `datetime` DESC
               LIMIT ' . (int) $failedLoginThreshold . ' ) `ul`
          ON ( u.`id` = ul.`user_id` )
        WHERE u.`email` = ' . Database::instance()->escape($email) . '
            AND u.`role_id` > 0
        GROUP BY u.`id`'
```

Using the information gathered, I can decide whether to log the user in, kick them as having a wrong password, or lock them out if they have attempted to login too many times incorrectly.

I just noticed when I `DROP`'d the table, none of the logins worked, because the subquery would return 0 rows.

SQL always gets me. How can I change this query so in the event of a user having never logged in before, it will allow them?

Of course I could enter a bogus row for every user, but it sounds too hacky for me (and prone to breakage).

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your `JOIN` into a `LEFT JOIN`. A `JOIN` defaults to `INNER JOIN`, which will not return a record unless a match was able to be made in the other table. Switching to `LEFT JOIN` tells MySQL to return records from the "left" table (i.e. your `users` table) even if there's no matching record in the "right" table (your `user_logins` table).